# Web API - Get Values from Querystring and Form Body

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an action in Web API with a route like the following:

```
/users/{userId}/friends
```

And I want to post a value to it with the following action:

```
[ActionName("friends")]
        public IHttpActionResult Friends2(string userId, [FromBody]string friendId)
```

I am posting JSON like:

```
{ "friendId": "123" }
```

However, the friendId is always null. I think this is because Web API only allows 1 parameter when specifying [FromBody].

So how can I post to this action with the userId coming from the querystring and the friendId coming as JSON in the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a view model that your controller action will take as parameter and bind to the JSON structure sent in the body:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string FriendId { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
ActionName("friends")]
public IHttpActionResult Friends2(string userId, MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```